# Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more information

Tags: kubernetes, kibana

I started EFK stack on k8s.

my ekf-kibana service manifest is as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-03-19T07:30:15Z"
  labels:
    app: kibana
    chart: kibana-0.4.3
    heritage: Tiller
    release: efk
  name: efk-kibana
  namespace: logging
  resourceVersion: "10156"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/logging/services/efk-kibana
  uid: d70a3266-4a18-11e9-b340-02edaf44024a
spec:
  clusterIP: 100.69.129.248
  ports:
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5601
  selector:
    app: kibana
    release: efk
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

when i access kibana using kube proxy URL as below

[image]

when kibana load some css and js in backend, it redirect to api URL instead of proxy and kibana base URL as per below screenshot.

[image]

please help!!!

Actually there is path related issue. below is my detailed explanation

```
NAME=cluster_name
```

kibana URL using proxy is

```
https://api.$NAME/api/v1/namespaces/logging/services/efk-kibana:443/proxy/app/kibana
```

it give error, kibana not loading properly and show for load some js and css from

```
https://api.$NAME/bundles/vendors.style.css
```

i set kibana server_basepath in kibana manifest is as below for open via proxy

```
/api/v1/namespaces/logging/services/efk-kibana
```

actually it should load from "API_URL+server_basepath/proxy/...." as below

```
https://api.$NAME/api/v1/namespaces/logging/services/efk-kibana:443/proxy/bundles/vendors.style.css
```

so there is some path related issue in kibana deployment or in docker image.

Comment: can you post your kibana logs?

Answer (score 3):

You can try alternative way to get into Kibana dashboard, with port-forward instead proxy command, like this:

```
kubectl port-forward service/efk-kibana 5000:443 -n logging
```

now open http://localhost:5000 in web browser

Comment: it's only useful when k8s created locally. for kops k8s, we need to run this command in all master node of k8s instead of kubectl from client.